# Making alerts prettier without rewriting many lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I know there are many good plugins for pretty alert boxes, but I have already made so many alerts, so I wanted to ask if it's possible to make those alerts prettier without rewriting  all `alert` function calls in the code and replacing this function with other?

Comment: You *could* create your own `alert` which would be shadowing the native one. It would be a wrapper calling the actual stylish one, but make sure you create a copy of the native one first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hijack the default `window.alert` function:

```
window.__oldAlert__ = window.alert;
window.alert = function () {
    // your custom alert code here
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/jMEha/

---

#### Edit

> what do I need to write to change it to this plugin? http://thrivingkings.com/apprise

Your page will need jQuery, and the Apprise JS and CSS files.

```
window.__oldAlert__ = window.alert;
window.alert = function () {
    apprise.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/exgBs/

Comment: ..and how to make actually this pretty? To me looks like an ordinary alert!... :(

Comment: That would be done using one of the alert box plugins that the OP mentioned.

Comment: lol :) shame to me... I just copy-pasted this! it's late... Better i go to 'kill' my eyes a bit... :)

Comment: I am sorry, but what do I need to write to change it to this plugin? http://thrivingkings.com/apprise/ Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no one who stops you from just overwritting the native `window.alert` method. If you are in charge of the codebase, this could look like:

```
(function _mynameSpace() {
    window.alert = function() { 
        $('#mydialogDiv').dialog({
            modal: true,
            // etc.
        });
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace `window.alert` with a function that performs a notification in some customized way. Here's a simple example:

```
<script>
  window.alert = console.log;
</script>
```

Subsequent calls to `alert` will really call `console.log`.